# How to get an array from html using angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

There is a given directive as an attribute ng-menu with the following array value:

```
<div data-ng-menu="['Home','Settings','About']"></div>
```

I need to list each item in this array like this:

- Home
- Settings
- About

I have tried something like this:

```
app.directive('ngMenu', function () {
    var menu = {};
    var getItems = function(scope, element, attributes) {
    //I suppose I should get the array value here
}
    menu.restrict = 'AEC';
    menu.link = getItems;
    template : '<ul>'
             + '<li>items</li>'
             + '</ul>';
    return menu;
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have read the Angular Doc but I didn't find a useful solution

Comment: "There is a given directive: ... data-ng-menu ...": Where is that directive? Did you write it? Post it's full source, if you want some useful help... If you nedd help writing it, specify more clearly how it should perform, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think this example is useful

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
        app.directive('menu', function () {
            debugger
            return {
                restrict: 'AEC',
                scope:{},
                link: function (scope, ele, attributes) {
                    scope.result = attributes.menu;
                },
               template: '<div>{{result}}</div>'
            }
        })
    </script>




</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="MyApp">
     <div menu="'Home','Settings','About'"></div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple reusable directive to display the desired output as a list.

**Angular code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items=['Home','Settings','About'];
});

myApp.directive('myMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      list: "="
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li></ul>'
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-menu list="items"></my-menu>
</div>
```

Hopefully it helps.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5sbb48fq/

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to evaluate attribute value:

```
var getItems = function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.menu = scope.$eval(attributes.ngMenu);
}
```

In above I'm assuming that you don't want to have an isolated scope. If however you do need it (which I would recommend you for this kind of directives), then you can use two-way binding:

```
app.directive('ngMenu', function() {
  var menu = {};
  var getItems = function(scope, element, attributes) {
    console.log(scope.menu); // array of items bound to the scope.menu
  }
  menu.scope = {
    menu: '=ngMenu'
  };
  menu.restrict = 'AEC';
  menu.link = getItems;
  menu.template = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in menu">{{item}}</li></ul>';
  return menu;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a simple directive example that will fit your needs:

https://jsfiddle.net/obx25af0/9/

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myMenu', function(){
    var link = function(scope, attrs, element){
    console.log(scope.menuItems);
    alert(scope.menuItems);
  }
    return {
    restrict: 'AE', //use as element or attribute
    scope: { //isolate scope
        'menuItems': '='
    },
    link: link
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div>
  <!-- You can use the directive as an attribute(restrict A)-->
  <div my-menu menu-items="['menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3']"></div>
  <!-- Or as an element(restrict E)-->
  <my-menu menu-items="['menu 4', 'menu 5', 'menu 6']"></my-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved like this:

```
app.directive('ngMenu', function () {
    var menu = {};
    var getItems = function($scope, element, attributes) {
       alert($scope.ngMenu); //$scope.ngMenu will have your array
    };
    menu.scope = {
       ngMenu: '@'
    };
    menu.restrict = 'AEC';
    menu.link = getItems;
    template : '<ul>'
             + '<li>items</li>'
             + '</ul>';
    return menu;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-menu="['Home','Settings','About']"></div>
```

Comment: *"$scope.ngMenu will have your array"* - no, it will a string.